# Arquillian Jersey ClientHandlerException

Tags: maven-3, jboss-arquillian

i am trying out Arquallian and I run into some trouble.

My simple test code,

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class Tests {

@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addClass(Query.class)
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
   }


   @Test
   public void testMeth() {

   }
}
```

i get following error messages:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for    Java type, class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart,and MIME media    type, multipart/form-data, was not found
 Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type, multipart/form-data, was not found
```

in the surefire reports is following written

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.ValidationException:DeploymentScenario contains a target (_DEFAULT_) not matching any defined Container in the registry.
Please include at least 1 Deployable Container on your Classpath.
```

The Project pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eu.enda.backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>enda-jpa-library</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>enda-jpa-api</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <!--<version>1.1.11.Final</version>-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <type>jar</type> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.enda</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.enda.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>enda-vaadin-library</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1.1</version>   
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.enda.querytool.backend</groupId>
            <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>            
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-glassfish-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

while i try to run the test a `GlassfishServer 4.1` is running.

I had a test project for `arquillian` with nearly the same setup and it worked fine i checked if i had forgotten something, but nothing is missing. 
The maven profile is correctly set.
The `test-persistence.xml` is under `src/test/resources`.

Answer (score 0):

On my version of the Arquilian documentation (French language), the pom.xml to test a remote Glassfish server looks different as there is in addition in glassfish remote profile:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
  <version>1.18</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As the documentation explains that Glassfish adapter needs Jersey Rest to communicate with container it could be that.

The second error just says that as arquilian fails to use a valid container, it can't run the tests.
I have the exact errors so I'm really interrested about the answer of that problem.

**Update :** As I went through some other answers, it seems that the versions of both jersey-multipart and jersey-bundle need to be 1.10. 
[Source](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/198633?tstart=0)